# Can rsync display current average speed?

Tags: performance, rsync

When I'm transferring large quantities of data using rsync, it would be helpful if I could have the average speed up until now at a glance, rather than a bunch of different speeds for each file.

Answer (score 92, accepted):

Yes. Starting with rsync version 3.1.0 the `--info=progress2` argument will give you progress on the entire transfer, including speed of the entire transfer. You can see a little bit of detail on [the rsync man page](http://rsync.samba.org/ftp/rsync/rsync.html).

Comment: I am using that and the speed and thus remaining time is still jumping around like crazy :/

Comment: There's more to interpreting the `--info=progress2` output than can fit in a comment. I did find an answer that I'm happy with that might give you a better feeling for what you're seeing and why you're seeing it: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/261139

Answer (score 16):

In case you're [not running v3.1.0](https://serverfault.com/a/607694/12294), rsync-3.0.9 takes the `--progress` flag.  The man page on my CentOS7 box reports

> This option tells rsync to print information showing the progress of the transfer. This gives a bored user something to watch.